# what wrong with that ? I wanna del redis key in laravel but it doesn't work .it return queue status

Tags: laravel, redis

what wrong with that ? I wanna del redis  key  in laravel but it doesn't work .it return queue status[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNfoa.png)

Comment: It seems your question is incomplete. Please make sure you add more code. For more Information, please read the SO  Guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queued` response is used in redis transactions. When you start a transaction with `multi` every command you execute will be `queued` until you `exec` it.

```
> MULTI
OK
> INCR foo
QUEUED
> INCR bar
QUEUED
> EXEC
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 1
```

Probably in your code, `exec` part is missing or you may remove `multi` before executing your command.